# Moving from Qt to Boost - Networking

Tags: boost-asio

I's using Qt to build Udp and Tcp servers/clients. Now in recent project, Qt is not allowed and i'm supposed to use Boost. Having gone through boost::asio, i feel confused since there are so many features and usages are very different from Qt. For Udp (multicast,broadcast etc) i'm more or less clear now. But for Tcp i'm having problems understanding:

(have to do all async)

1. TCP is stream oriented so there is no way to know the number of bytes that have arrived. So we use `asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_read_some()`. However in Qt we have `readAll()` for a socket which can be made to read all data on `readyRead()` signal and return a `QByteArray`, the size of which we needn't specify as it can grow. How do i achieve this in Boost? `readyRead()` signal i think would map roughly to `async_read_some()`, what about the rest (`readAll()` and "growable" `buffer`/array?
2. `disconnected`() signal is emitted in Qt if the TCP connection disconnects (server/client off, lan cable unplugged etc). What would be the equivalent check in Boost? Do i need a timer to periodically send and expect heartbeat messages myself?

Comment: this question would be better if you include specifics about your application and environment: the protocol(s) in use, and any assumptions about networking configuration such as TCP keep-alive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use some overload of `async_read` [free function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) with the appropriate completion-condition.
   As you see there, this function accepts `asio::streambuf`, which is growing automatically.
2. Yes, the only portable & reliable way is to send some heartbeat. I don't know how Qt does that, but try cutting the network cable and see whether you get any notification from Qt...

Comment: `async_read(AsyncReadStream & s,basic_streambuf< Allocator > & b,CompletionCondition completion_condition,ReadHandler handler);` seems to be it then. As for the completion condition, should i return `tcp::socket::available()` ? (since return value of 0 serves as the completion condition). As for <2>, my networking isn't particularly sound, but shouldn't i expect async_read(..) to call it's handler immediately with some kind of error set if the connection disrupts? I ask again because if something needed to be sent, Qt would be doing it and i would have received it in readAll()

Comment: @ustulation 1) `async_read`, of course - I'll edit the link. As for completion condition - it is a functor, it's not a value. If you want to read as much as possible - use `transfer_all` condition, if you want to read exact number of bytes - use `transfer_exact` etc (see other predefined condition functors). 2) Of course, if some error occurs any async.operation completes with an error value - the problem is that the TCP/IP stack doesn't always know that something bad happened!

Comment: R : " As for completion condition - it is a functor, it's not a value." - :) i know..what i meant was the signature should have the return value as size_t. If the return value is 0 it is taken as a termination condition - ie., registered callback function is invoked. If that is the case returning `tcp::socket::available()` from the completion condition function/functor should make it simulate Qt's `readAll()`. This is what i's asking.

Comment: One more thing: i do not know the behaviour of completion condition. I'm assuming that since free standing version of `asio::async_read()` makes a series of calls to socket's `async_read_some()` (as is mentioned at the boost's reference site), each time it does it checks the completion condition. If this condition returns `tcp::socket::available()` then eventually when there is no more data to read it'll return 0 and registered handler to `async_read()` will be called. I hope there is no undefined behaviour / wrong assumptions anywhere.

Comment: @ustulation well, you can make completion-condition that returns `socket::available()`, but note that even if it returns zero, it might return non-zero a few moments later... I'm not quite familiar with Qt socket, but IUUC it utilizes "reactor" approach, i.e. you wait until some data is available and then read it. ASIO implements "proactor" pattern: issue an async.read and supply buffer - and when data is available, you get the data and a notification. The question whether it was *all* the data or not seems rather meaningless in terms of TCP.